# High fan speed and CPU temp with low CPU usage?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, power-management

I've been having intermittent fan speed and high CPU temperature when my CPU usage is nearly 0%. I don't run any weird apps. If I put my computer into sleep mode and wake it back up, this fixes the issue. I think this is an System Management Controller(SMC) issue, but I'm not sure. Anyone know how to fix this permanently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [resetting the SMC](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964) as noted in the question for your MacBook Air and see if the problem persists.

If the problem does persist it may be a failing temperature sensor, resulting in the fans running faster than normal to worst case fail-safe full-speed state, your only option at that point would be to take it to [Apple Support](http://www.apple.com/support/contact/) for repair / replacement.

Comment: Thank you @MrDaniel. I don't think it's in fail-safe because that's usually on/off which means maximum speed, however, it's not maximum speed. I'd say it's about 40% speed.

Comment: Still could be a failing sensor reading hotter than it actually is, if the SMC reset is not fixing it, than something with hardware / sensors might be going wonky.

Answer (score 0):

If its a laptop, spin it upside down and blast some air into the vents. The idea is to blow out any dust that may be causing the computer to overheat.

I usually just take a deep breath and give it a good blasting...